# How can remove Nginx from http response header?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, hide

I want to remove Nginx from http response header. I can Hide my Nginx version but I want to hide Nginx too.
Thanks

Comment: Adding a comment for those ending here searching like me.

If your Nginx is dealing mostly with upstream servers (and if not you can always make your actual server config an upstream of an extra webserver), you can use `proxy_hide_headers` to remove the headers coming from the upstream in the response

Answer (score 32):

Use the `ngx_headers_more` module - see http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule.

It allows you to configure any arbitrary headers you'd like - both request and response headers.  Once you've installed it (and thus recompiled your version of Nginx), use the following configuration:

```
more_set_headers 'Server: my-server';
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a `Server` header at all, then clear it using:

```
more_clear_headers 'Server';
```